# Image resized error: CGBitmapContextCreate: unsupported parameter

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using the following code (from a blog post) to resize an image

```
if (inImage.size.width <= inImage.size.height) {
    // Portrait
    ratio = inImage.size.height / inImage.size.width;
    resizedRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, width * ratio);
}
else {
    // Landscape
    ratio = inImage.size.width / inImage.size.height;
    resizedRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, height * ratio, height);
}

CGImageRef          imageRef = [inImage CGImage];
CGImageAlphaInfo    alphaInfo = CGImageGetAlphaInfo(imageRef);

if (alphaInfo == kCGImageAlphaNone)
    alphaInfo = kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast;

CGContextRef bitmap = CGBitmapContextCreate(
                                            NULL,
                                            resizedRect.size.width,     // width
                                            resizedRect.size.height,        // height
                                            CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef),   // really needs to always be 8
                                            4 * resizedRect.size.width, // rowbytes
                                            CGImageGetColorSpace(imageRef),
                                            alphaInfo
                                            );
```

but for some reason depending on the size I am try to resize to I get the following error generated

> CGBitmapContextCreate: unsupported
>   parameter combination: 8 integer
>   bits/component; 32 bits/pixel;
>   3-component colorspace;
>   kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst; XXX
>   bytes/row.

where XXX differs depending on which image.

The rect I am creating is propotional to the image, I take a ratio from the width/height (depending on aspect) and multiple that be target width/height.

Here are some examples (X errors, / doesnt), the resize size will be 50xX or Xx50 depending on aspect:

```
Source   50x50   69x69
430x320  /      X
240x320  /      /
272x320  /      /
480x419  /      X
426x320  X      X
480x256  X      X
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Where you wrote `thumbRect`, did you mean `resizedRect`? `thumbRect` does not otherwise occur.

I suspect the problem is that `resizedRect.size.width` is non integral.  Note that it's floating point.

The width and bytesPerRow parameters of `CGBitmapContextCreate` are declared as integers.  When you pass a floating point value, such as here, it gets truncated.

Suppose your resizedRect.size.width is 1.25.  Then you will end up passing 1 for the width, and floor(1.25 * 4) == 5 as the bytes per row.  That's inconsistent.  You always want to pass four times whatever you passed for the width for the bytes per row.

You can also just leave bytesPerRow as 0, by the way.  Then the system picks the best bytesPerRow (which is often larger than 4 times the width - it pads out for alignment).

Comment: yes (copy and paste error formatting it as a question)

yes I agree resizedRect.size.width will probably be a floating point. Could you explain a little more, do I just need to round to integer?

Comment: please just updated your response, I did just cast the 3 usages of the values to int and it sorted the problem.

(int)resizedRect.size.width etc

Comment: I've set bytesPerRow as 0 already, but still get the error when the size in float value. 
CGContextConcatCTM: invalid context 0x0
CGContextSetInterpolationQuality: invalid context 0x0
CGContextDrawImage: invalid context 0x0
CGBitmapContextCreateImage: invalid context 0x0